# How do I get XSLT to express an attribute wherever it appears in the least invasive way?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have XSLT 1.0 like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Only, there are lots and lots of templates that are similar to the first one. I would like to have a specific attribute emitted in each of these templates, but I want to make the least invasive change to pull it off. Here's the first thing I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@class">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:value-of select="@class"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But that didn't work. I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <p>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="@class"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But to make that work in every template would require a lot of code duplication. Is that the best I can do, or is there a more appropriate way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your initial attempt

```
  <xsl:template match="@class">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:value-of select="@class"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
```

the context node for this template is the `class` attribute node, therefore the `value-of` should select `.`:

```
  <xsl:template match="@class">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
```

However you should also note that a bare `<xsl:apply-templates/>` only applies templates matching *children* of the current node, and since attribute nodes do not count as children in the XSLT data model this `@class` template won't fire.  You probably need to modify your `paragraph` template to say

```
  <xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
```

to apply templates that match the `paragraph` element's attributes as well as its children.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! In my particular case I had a problem with `select="@*"`. Apparently somewhere in this really huge XSLT that I'm maintaining there are other templates that cause interaction problems. I used `select="@class|node()"` instead, which works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you really don't want to make any change to the existing template rules, then add a template rule with higher priority than the rules for "p", etc, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@class]" priority="100">
  <xsl:variable name="v">
    <xsl:next-match/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$v" mode="add-attribute">
    <xsl:with-param name="att" select="@class"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="add-attribute">
  <xsl:param name="att" as="attribute()"/>
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="@*, $att"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In 1.0 you would have to put this in a separate module and use apply-imports rather than next-match.

Comment: This looks like the best way to go, but I'm unable to get it to work with XSLT 1.0. I replaced `<xsl:next-match/>` with `<xsl:apply-imports/>` (all the templates I'm interested in are already imported from other stylesheets). Then I get problems with `select="@*, $att"` and `mode="#current"`. I wish I could use XSLT 2.0.